# session-factory tag in hibernate configuration file?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria, sessionfactory

I am new `Hibernate` learner.
I am confused, Why we use the tag `session-factory` in hibernate configuration file 
?

We are also using it inside the main class to create a session factory object for all transactions.

Answer (score 2):

In Hibernate the `SessionFactory` is used **to manage sessions and transactions with database**, as you can see in the **[documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html)**:

> The main contract here is the **creation of Session instances**. Usually **an application has a single SessionFactory instance** and **threads servicing client requests obtain Session instances from this factory**.
>
> The internal state of a SessionFactory is immutable. Once it is
>   created this internal state is set. This internal state includes all
>   of the metadata about Object/Relational Mapping.

## EDIT:

The `<session factory>` tag in XML configuration file is used to **configure** and **initialize** the session factory settings for hibernate such as `Dialect` class and connection `Driver` class properties and you can see at **[Hibernate - Configuration](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_configuration.htm)** that *the XML configuration file must conform to the Hibernate 3 Configuration DTD*.

While the `sessionFactory` instance that we use in our classes is used to manage session for each database transaction, you can find more details about it in [jBossDeveloper's **Sessions and transactions** tutorial](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/SessionsAndTransactions).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I understand that to manage sessions, we use session factory.
But why we use twice 
First inside configuration file <session factory> tag
Second inside main class, while creating session factory object.
then
What is the use of this tag <session factory>  in configuration file ?

Comment: @Nilay take a look at my Edit.

Answer (score 0):

In Hibernate to perform Database operations we reqired connection with the database.To open connection with database we require session object in hibernate,To get Session object we need Hibernate SessionFactory which is the factory class through which we get sessions and perform database operations. Hibernate SessionFactory provides three methods through which we can get Session object – getCurrentSession(), openSession() and openStatelessSession().

Hibernate SessionFactory getCurrentSession() method returns the session bound to the context. But for this to work, we need to configure it in hibernate configuration file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand that to manage sessions, we use session factory. But why we use twice First inside configuration file <session factory> tag Second inside main class, while creating session factory object. then What is the use of this tag <session factory> in configuration file ?